# enable Joomla 2.5 website to run on PHP 5.4.0 +

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I upgraded my PHP version on my shared server (on a2hosting.com) to PHP 5.4.0 + and an error occurred on all my hosted Joomla 2.5 websites (Internal Server Error...). When I change the PHP back to 5.3.8 the websites work.

So my question is how can I modify (or what shall i do to) my Joomla 2.5 website files to work on PHP 5.4.0 +?

I want to use PHP 5.4.0 + because i'm currently developing websites with Joomla 3.x

Thanks

Comment: Joomla 2.5 is working in php 5.4 without a problem.

Comment: If you're still puzzeled by this: You first need to find out what PHP reported into the error log: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456)

Answer (score 1):

It does seem as problem in your `.htaccess` file. 
 You should try to uncoment this line `# RewriteBase /`

Or you could try to change name of .htaccess to htaccess.txt thus make it inactive and see if this works.

If so, you should change your name back and try to comment lines in this file and see which one is making the problem.

Also it could be PHP 5.4.0 depending on your exact Joomla version, check this http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=622&t=726130